# Using Box<> with HashMap<> in Rust

Tags: rust, hashmap

I need to create a large `HashMap` in Rust, which is why I thought of using the `Box` to use the heap memory.
My question is about what is the best way to keep this data, certainly I only thought of two possible ways (anticipating that I am not so experienced with Rust).

---

```rust
fn main() {
  let hashmap = Box<HashMap<u64, DataStruct>>;
  ...
}
```

OR

```rust
fn main() {
  let hashmap = HashMap<u64, Box<DataStruct>>;
  ...
}
```

---

**What is the best way to handle such a thing?

Thanks a lot.**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

HashMap already stores its data on the heap, you don't need to box your values.

> Just like vectors, hash maps store their data on the heap. This
> HashMap has keys of type String and values of type i32. Like vectors,
> hash maps are homogeneous: all of the keys must have the same type,
> and all of the values must have the same type.

[Source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch08-03-hash-maps.html#creating-a-new-hash-map)

Comment: I had never found this information in the Rust documentation.

Comment: @Giuseppe the docs don't seem to mention this, but the Rust Book does: "Just like vectors, hash maps store their data on the heap." https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch08-03-hash-maps.html#creating-a-new-hash-map

Comment: Just to add: as a rule of thumb, almost anything that is *dynamic* will use the heap, because the stack has to be known at compile-time. That means things that can expand (Vecs and HashMaps, as you can add elements), that have an indeterministic life (Arcs and Rcs allocations, as they decide when to deallocate, based on reference counting), or that have an unknown size (trait objects, recursive structures) will be allocated on the heap, as they cannot be statically defined at compile-time.

Comment: @RedBorg but in cases of recursive structures and `dyn Trait` you have to explicitly use `Box`, right?

Comment: I've found an example [here](https://www.simonewebdesign.it/rust-hashmap-insert-values-multiple-types/)

Comment: @IvanC you need to use `Box` if your struct is recursive, but using owned `dyn Trait` without a `Box` may be possible in the future via Variable Lenght Arrays. They are not the same thing, but they use the same underlying structure.

Comment: Are HashMap values reference stable? If not, then I think there are some applications where boxed values may still be required (e.g. hashmaps who values are linked), especially when using unsafe Rust.

Comment: @jmracek I don't think Box has address stability guarantees either.